# Update Column based on another column and Delete data from the other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets assume the df looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'fname':['Anky','Anky','Tom','Harry','Harry','Harry'],'lname':['sur1','sur1','sur2','sur3','sur3','sur3'],'role':['','abc','def','ghi','','ijk'],'mobile':['08511663451212','+4471123456','0851166346','','0851166347',''],'Pmobile':['085116634512','1234567890','8885116634','','+353051166347','0987654321']})

import numpy as np
df.replace('',np.nan,inplace=True)
```

df:

```
    fname   lname   role    mobile          Pmobile         
0   Anky    sur1    NaN    08511663451212   085116634512    
1   Anky    sur1    abc    +4471123456      1234567890      
2   Tom     sur2    def    0851166346       8885116634      
3   Harry   sur3    ghi    NaN              NaN             
4   Harry   sur3    NaN    0851166347       +353051166347   
5   Harry   sur3    ijk    NaN              0987654321
```

So I want to update the column `mobile` with values from `Pmobile` where the values starts with `'08','8','+353` and simultaneously it should delete the value from `Pmobile` field where it finds a match and copies data to `mobile` field.

Presently I am getting this by :

```
df.mobile.update(df['Pmobile'][df['Pmobile'].str.startswith(('08','8','+353'),na=False)])
df.Pmobile[df.mobile==df.Pmobile] = np.nan
```

df:

```
    fname   lname   role    mobile          Pmobile 
0   Anky    sur1    NaN     085116634512    NaN 
1   Anky    sur1    abc     +4471123456     1234567890  
2   Tom     sur2    def     8885116634      NaN 
3   Harry   sur3    ghi     NaN             NaN 
4   Harry   sur3    NaN     +353051166347   NaN 
5   Harry   sur3    ijk     NaN             0987654321
```

Is there a way to do this on the fly?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to shift the columns left do this:

```
In[50]:

df.loc[df['Pmobile'].str.startswith(('08','8','+353'),na=False), ['mobile','Pmobile']] = df[['mobile','Pmobile']].shift(-1,axis=1)
df
Out[50]: 
   fname lname role         mobile     Pmobile
0   Anky  sur1  NaN   085116634512         NaN
1   Anky  sur1  abc    +4471123456  1234567890
2    Tom  sur2  def     8885116634         NaN
3  Harry  sur3  ghi            NaN         NaN
4  Harry  sur3  NaN  +353051166347         NaN
5  Harry  sur3  ijk            NaN  0987654321
```

So use your condition to mask the rows of interest and then assign the result of those 2 columns shifted left by 1 where the condition is met.

This will leave a `NaN` where the value has shifted and do nothing where the condition isn't met

Comment: Excellent answer. That's what I was looking for .Thanks a ton. :)